# Compiling FFmpeg in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg

I want to implement FFmpeg functionality in iOS which can hide/show images at sepcific frames. I was able to built ffmpeg library and compile in Xcode as Objective-C project but not in Swift. The error in Swift is “‘d3d11.h’ file not found” from file d3d11va.h.

The file was build from here [kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script.)

Comment: Header-bridge Objective-C files into a Swift project.

Comment: Hey, Got it running. But, I had another issue. After some tweaks like modifying Architecture(Removing arm64) and other changes, I had an error **Duplicate symbol _main** from 2 files - one of ffmpeg and other on AppDelegate.swift. By removing AppDelegate from **Compile Sources**, the project compiled successfully. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Got that too. It was due to main methods in AppDelegate.swift(internally) and in ffmpeg.c file.I just renamed main method of ffmpeg.c and included in ffmpeg.h file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great quick start guide in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72673294/921573

Summary:

- download the compiled lib e.g. https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/releases/download/v4.5.1/ffmpeg-kit-full-4.5.1-macos-xcframework.zip
- move the xcframeworks into your project
- enjoy ffmpeg