# Do I need one .framework per .dylib for an iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, packaging

In an iOS application that depends on ffmpeg, I'm faced with the issue that the App Store does not accept dylibs that are embedded directly in the app bundle. [This technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING) says

> Dynamic libraries outside of a framework bundle, which typically have the file extension .dylib, are not supported on iOS, watchOS, or tvOS, except for the system Swift libraries provided by Xcode

But it's not obvious to me, does this mean that in the case of ffmpeg, I would need one framework per dylib, or am I allowed to package all ffmpeg dylibs into a single framework and use *that* in my app bundle?

Comment: That means that you must include ffmpeg as a static library (.a file) that is linked to the’’build the exe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ffmpeg for use in iOS application coded in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672889/ffmpeg-for-use-in-ios-application-coded-in-swift)

Comment: @PtitXav This does not answer the question. I only mentioned ffmpeg to provide context on what exactly I'm trying to do, but my question is more generic. Static linking is off the table due to license constraints.

Comment: So, if the dynamic lib is not in iOS system you are doomed

Comment: @PtitXav I appreciate your comment but I think you are mistaken. I can ship the dylibs I'm sure, I'm just not sure about the layout requirements in the app bundle. Hence, my question.

Comment: May be this [package](https://swiftpackageindex.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS) is what you need.